# Interface Builder

Tags: iphone

What is the difference between creating an IPhone application using Interface Builder and without it?

Comment: please go and read http://stackoverflow.com/faq ('How do I ask questions here?'). This question is 'OK', but you need to learn how to continue after asking ..

Answer (score 0):

Interface builder is simply an application that can help you place GUI elements and then associate IBOutlets and other in-code functions. you can go into Dashcode and actually read the code generated by Interface Builder but I think you will find that it is LONG and repetitive. Interface builder simply makes it easier to get the interface elements where and how you want them using a GUI. you don't NEED it but its sure useful.

you can create a full interface without an .xib or interfacebuilder you just have to write more code.